# Export plugin omits many images

Tags: import

I think I have never seen the [WP Importer plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) work perfectly a single time. It always skips a few featured images.

Is there a manual and hopefully more reliable procedure to export and import all posts/CPT with featured images?

Comment: Do you see any timeout message while importing ? Does this process ends successfully ?

Comment: I have never had trouble with the Importer plugin. You are going to need to provide more information about your particular issue.

Comment: @Subharanjan: no, the process didn't end at all. It lasted forever and so I forgot about it then I turned my PC off. But then, this is what I always experienced every time I used this plugin: it never completes. I'm very surprised to hear that s_ha_dum has never had trouble with the plugin. I have the exact opposite experience.